# Ruby coding: Sequence of number pairs "x,y" such that x ranges from 0 to 3 and y from 5 to 7

Tags: ruby

I am stuck on this problem. I tried to solve it with Ruby.

My answer is

```
4.times{|i| puts "#{i}"} && 5.upon(7){|i| puts "#{i}}
```

but, I am not sure that it is correct or not.

Comment: you want `[[0,5],[0,6],[0,7],[1,5]......]` ?

Answer (score 5):

This should work for you

```
result = (0..3).to_a.product((5..7).to_a)
puts result.inspect
#=> [[0, 5], [0, 6], [0, 7], [1, 5], [1, 6], [1, 7], [2, 5], [2, 6], [2, 7], [3, 5], [3, 6], [3, 7]]
```

Comment: (0..3) and (5..7) but otherwise, this is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> not sure that it is correct or not

Generally, in such a case, you try to run the code. Had you done so, you would have noticed (incrementally) that you have a quote missing, that there is no such method as `Fixnum#upon` (`upto` would have done it), that the code only outputs a single digit at a time and never a pair, and that the second loop does not run (since `times` returns `nil`, and `nil && x` gets short-circuited so that `x` does not evaluate).

As to your question, it asks for the sequence of number pairs, and not for its display, so `puts` is not needed. Also, since you need pairs, you should have the two loops nested, not one after another.

```
(0..3).flat_map { |x| (4..7).map { |y| [x, y] } }
```

would be one easy way to write it.

EDIT: `flat_map` is cooler than `map.flatten`. Still, macek's answer is more specific +1.